# How to cbind all combinations of rows of a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, recursion, combinations, apply

I have a list of matrices. The length of this list is unknown (although for my example I use a list of 3 2x2 matrices).

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    4    4

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    6    6
```

From this list I would like to generate a matrix of all possible combinations of the rows of each matrix in the list. I.e. I want this as oputput:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    3    3    5    5
[2,]    2    2    3    3    5    5
[3,]    1    1    4    4    5    5
[4,]    2    2    4    4    5    5
[5,]    1    1    3    3    6    6
[6,]    2    2    3    3    6    6
[7,]    1    1    4    4    6    6
[8,]    2    2    4    4    6    6
```

I have looked at other examples (e.g. i would love to use expand.grid) but all tend to expand combinations of the elements of the rows or apply some other function which I have not been able to adapt.

Also - needs to work on any sized list of matrices.

I have a solution but am sure that there must be a better / shorter / more elegant / faster one hiding somewhere. Can you help me find it?

This is my code:

```
# New matrix will be stored in here.
# Don't like but is there a better way?
m.combs <- c()

expand.grid.2 <- function(lst) {

  if (is.null(m.combs)) {

    m.combs <<- lst

  } else {

    m.current <- m.combs
    n <- nrow(m.combs)

    for (i in 1:nrow(lst)) {

      if(i == 1)  # for first iteration cbind new matrix
        m.combs <<- cbind(m.combs, matrix(rep(lst[i, ], each = n), nrow = n))
      else        # for next iterations rbind new matrix
        m.combs <<- rbind(m.combs, cbind(m.current, matrix(rep(lst[i, ], each = n), nrow = n)))
    }
  }
}

m1 <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
m2 <- matrix(c(3,3,4,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
m3 <- matrix(c(5,5,6,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
lst <- list(m1, m2, m3)

rapply(lst, expand.grid.2)
print(m.combs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

```r
## get indices of all row combinations
m.combs <- expand.grid(lapply(l, function(x) seq_len(nrow(x))))

## extract rows and combine into matrix
do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) x[y, ], l, m.combs))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    1    3    3    5    5
#> [2,]    2    2    3    3    5    5
#> [3,]    1    1    4    4    5    5
#> [4,]    2    2    4    4    5    5
#> [5,]    1    1    3    3    6    6
#> [6,]    2    2    3    3    6    6
#> [7,]    1    1    4    4    6    6
#> [8,]    2    2    4    4    6    6
```

First use `expand.grid` to get the row indices (per list element) corresponding to all combinations we wish to generate. Second, extract the corresponding rows and combine them into a single matrix.

**Data**

```r
mat <- matrix(rep(1:6, 2), ncol = 2)
l <- list(mat[1:2, ], mat[3:4, ], mat[5:6, ])
```

Comment: Wow! And that is exactly the type of short, fast, elegant solution I was hoping for!! Thank you so much!

Comment: The second line can be simplified with `mapply`: `do.call(cbind, mapply(function(x, y) x[y, ], l, m.combs, SIMPLIFY = F))`.

Comment: @mt1022: Nice one, I edited the response using `Map`